# I'm unable to report a potentially malicious comment on Super User

Tags: discussion, comments

I stumbled across [a comment on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/67449/turn-off-change-file-extension-warning-in-windows-7/401576#comment2263650_401576) with a bit.ly link to a Google drive containing exe files:

> [image: comment with possible malicious link]

It actually looks fairly innocuous in its context, but VirusTotal gives a detection result of 4/71. I'm sure these could just be false positives but I figured I should still report it anyway. However I'm not able to report the comment, nor the answer, nor the question. I assume this is due to having only 1 rep. Thus I figured I'd ask about it on meta.superuser.com, but that requires 5 rep (yay).

[VirusTotal results](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/98413957d4f8e43f7cedb8d86a94fea3b25ee7252f11a57f2dbed5088445429a/detection) for the file I scanned, *no-extension-modify-dialog-en.exe*

**Related question:** [Why can't I report a bad answer on Super User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331261/why-cant-i-report-a-bad-answer-on-super-user)

Comment: To flag posts and comments which are not yours you need 15 reputation points

Comment: You can always hang on the chat and tell us about the issue. I reported the comment as of now. You will need 5 rep to enter though. With some suggested edits, you can gain some reputation.

Comment: @CaldeiraG that's not correct. Posting on chat requires 20 reputation. With 1 rep, a user can't interact in any way with other users or the moderators, except on their own posts.

Comment: that's a bit of a pickle. I'm in not in a situation where I can check it myself but I'll throw it someone folks can take a look. I'll also kick this over to MSU so we have a better chance that the SU community can take a lok

Comment: You can try compiling it yourself to see if the website have the same result. I think it's not uncommon for virus scanner to complain on non-"official" programs.

Comment: Just an FYI most user compiled scripts are going to set off most virus scanners (not that I would be running random exe's from the internet)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A potential workaround:

*Any* site on the stack exchange network, when you scroll down to the footer, your find that link that says *Contact*:

[image: screenshot-footer]

When you click on that, you *could* select the "Other" category and describe your issue.

Sure, that is an awkward way to go about "content moderation", but in the end, you are correct: you need those minimal amounts of reputation in order to either comment, flag, or write up a site-meta post. So, when you can't get to that minimal reputation, or don't want to, reporting via "Contact" would be one option.

Comment: Except this is hardly ever checked...

Comment: @S.S.Anne It was, once, and may be again.